# IntelliJ - cannot run Kotlin Class in mixed (Java/Kotlin) mode

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea

[image]

I am constantly getting the error (bottom right), but I have configured everything to run Kotlin/Java together. So, where is the missing bit which I cannot see.

**UPDATE**

A comment indicated that my pkg name was wrong, but it didn't matter regardless, as the below updated screenshot shows

[image]

Regards,

Comment: your package signature is wrong

Comment: @IłyaBursov     yes that was  typo, but I edited the file, restarted, and yet - same thing. Check the updated image

Comment: compare your code with sample from https://play.kotlinlang.org/byExample/01_introduction/01_Hello%20world

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to write the main function without any parameters, it has to be outside of the class like this:

```
package org.example

fun main() {
    println("Hello World!")
}
```

Note that in this case, the main function will be inside an artificial implicit class that is called like the containing file suffixed with `Kt`. This means, that in your example where you place the main function inside a file `AppKt.kt`, the resulting main class is called `AppKtKt`.

If you want to have the main function inside a class, you have to specify a parameter for the arguments. Also, it needs to be static, i.e. it has to be inside an object and must be annotated with `@JvmStatic`.
This can be done by declaring an object:

```
object AppKt {
        @JvmStatic
        fun main(args: Array<String>) {
            println("Hello World!")
        }
}
```

Or you can put the main function inside the companion object of a class:

```
class AppKt {
    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        fun main(args: Array<String>) {
            println("Hello World!")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Kotlin, your main function goes outside any class definition.

Comment: It _can_, but it doesn't _have_ to (iirc).

Comment: @Slaw only if you put it in a singleton `object` and mark it `@JvmStatic`.