# Kotlin + Gradle - Error: Could not find or load main class

Tags: kotlin, gradle, console-application

I'm trying to create a console application with Kotlin, so when trying to run the jar, it returns the message "Could not find or load main class". When I run it through IntelliJ, it runs normally but when I try to run it via the command line `java -jar C:\wavecounter\bin\wavecounter_service.jar`, the error occurs.

`WaveCounterService.kt`

```
package br.com.mawan.waveCounterService

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    println("Hello world!!")
}
```

`build.gradle`

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version '1.3.72'
}

group = "br.com.mawan.waveCounterService"
version = "1.0.0"

ext {
    dir_install = "c:\\wavecounter"
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
    maven { setUrl("https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/exposed") }
}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.3.72")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.3.72")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.exposed:exposed:0.10.4")
    implementation("org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.26")
    implementation("ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.3")
    implementation("ch.qos.logback:logback-core:1.2.3")
    implementation("com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.3.5")

    implementation("com.microsoft.sqlserver:mssql-jdbc:9.4.1.jre8")
    implementation("mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.18")
    implementation("net.sourceforge.jtds:jtds:1.3.1")
}

compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}

task backup_file_config(type: Copy) {
    from "${dir_install}\\config\\config_service.json"
    into "src/main/resources/"
}

task copy_files_bin(type: Copy) {
    from "${buildDir}\\libs\\wavecounter_service-${version}.jar"
    into "${dir_install}\\bin"
    rename ("wavecounter_service-${version}.jar", "wavecounter_service.jar")
}

task waveCounterServiceJar(type: Jar) {
    duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.INCLUDE
    manifest {
        attributes 'Implementation-Title': 'WaveCounterService',
                'Main-Class': 'br.com.mawan.waveCounterService.WaveCounterServiceKt'
    }
    archivesBaseName = "wavecounter_service"
    configurations.implementation.setCanBeResolved(true)
    from {
        exclude '**/module-info.class'
        configurations.implementation.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }
    with jar

    doFirst {
        mkdir "${dir_install}\\backup\\mysql"
    }

    finalizedBy(copy_files_bin, backup_file_config)
}
```

Comment: What is the content of `C:\wavecounter\bin\wavecounter_service.jar` if you unzip it? Gradle has the [application plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/application_plugin.html) to help building executable jars - have you tried that? Kotlin 1.3.72 is a pretty old version, but that shouldn't cause the problem you're seeing.

Comment: Maybe this can help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/72499623/15375588

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem but I can't explain why it worked. If anyone knows I would spend an explanation. I was looking at an old project and in its gradle there was the command "*exclude 'META-INF/*.RSA'*". I put this command in the jar creation task and it worked.

```
task waveCounterServiceJar(type: Jar) {
    exclude 'META-INF/*.RSA'
    duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.INCLUDE
    manifest {
        attributes 'Implementation-Title': 'WaveCounterService',
                'Main-Class': 'br.com.mawan.waveCounterService.WaveCounterServiceKt'
    }
    archivesBaseName = "wavecounter_service"
    configurations.implementation.setCanBeResolved(true)
    from {
        exclude '**/module-info.class'
        configurations.implementation.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }
    with jar

    doFirst {
        mkdir "${dir_install}\\backup\\mysql"
    }

    finalizedBy(copy_files_bin, backup_file_config)
}
```